# Cannot properly sign Twitter OAuth 1 request

Tags: java, scala, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to sign an OAuth 1 token request, specifically:

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
```

GitHub Gist [HERE](https://gist.github.com/alexflav23/6407319), easier to read:

```
  def timestamp: String = (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000).toString;
  def nonce: String = System.nanoTime.toString

  /**
   * Generates the OAuth 1 header for a request.
   */
  def oauthHeader(
    endPoint: String,
    requestMethod: String,
    consumerKey: String,
    callback: String,
    params: List[(String, String)] = List()): String = {
    val signature = sign(endPoint, requestMethod, consumerKey);
    val oauthParams: List[(String, String)] = params :::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_consumer_key -> consumerKey) ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_callback -> URLEncoder.encode(callback, UTF_8)) ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_nonce -> nonce) ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_timestamp -> timestamp) ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_signature -> signature) ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_signature_method -> "HMAC-SHA1") ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_version -> "1.0") :: Nil

    val encodedParams = oauthParams.sortBy(_._1) map (header => {
      header._1 + "=" + "\"" + header._2 + "\""
    })

    OAuthParams.oauth + " " + encodedParams.mkString(", ")
  }

  def sign(endPoint: String,
    requestMethod: String,
    consumerKey: String,
    params: List[(String, String)] = List()): String = {

    /**
     * The map of OAuth params.
     * Added to every request.
     */
    val oauthParams: List[(String, String)] = params :::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_consumer_key -> consumerKey) ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_nonce -> nonce) ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_timestamp -> timestamp) ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_signature_method -> "HMAC-SHA1") ::
      (OAuthParams.oauth_version -> "1.0") ::
      Nil

    /**
     * Percent encoded List of parameters.
     */
    val signatureMap = oauthParams.sortBy(_._1).map(header => {
      URLEncoder.encode(header._1 + "=" + header._2, UTF_8)
    });

    /**
     * Add the request method.
     */
    val encodedHeader = requestMethod ::
      URLEncoder.encode(endPoint, UTF_8) ::
      URLEncoder.encode(oauthParams.mkString("&"), UTF_8) :: Nil

    URLEncoder.encode(hmacSha1(encodedHeader.mkString("&"), signinKey), UTF_8);
  }

  def hmacSha1(value: String, key: String): String = {
    val keyBytes = key.getBytes();
    val signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
    val mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
    mac.init(signingKey);
    val rawHmac = mac.doFinal(value.getBytes());
    Base64.encodeBase64String(rawHmac)
  }
```

I keep getting: Failed to validate oauth signature and token.

Provided:

- the application is registered
- the "Sign in with Twitter" is enabled in the app settings

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to roll out my own OAuth 1.0a request signer.

Here's the HMAC-SHA1 part of it.

https://gist.github.com/alexflav23/6407319

The full implementation will go in a `net.databinder.dispatch` pull request.

Answer (score 0):

The first problems that I see are with the generation of the nonce and the timestamp. Both of these are methods that have the potential to produce a different value every time they are called. If these have different values in the signature rather than the header, then they will cause the server to generate a different signature that doesn't match the one that you provide.

Have you considered using a library?

I know that [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) and the [Play WS API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaWS) both offer support for OAuth requests. I believe that Play! uses [Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/) and I've also had luck in Java using this code from the OAuth website http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/